# put() prints duplicate lines in c

Tags: c, string, while-loop, newline, eof

i was trying to run following code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>

void main()
{  
        int c;
        while((c=getchar()) !=EOF)
                        putchar(c);
                        }
```

i typed "hi" (or any other word) only once and when i press enter its print same thing again with a new line, no matter how large the line is

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y67i.png)

i dont know whats happening , the input stream is not buffered

Comment: What output did you expect? Please [edit] your question to include the input, actual and expected output *as text*. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The code is doing what you tell it to! You input characters, one at a time, and print each one, one at a time. Maybe add a `putchar('\n');` in your `while` loop, to see what's actually happening.

Comment: i expect that when i type "hi" and press enter it takes me to new line instead of new line and does not print "hi" again.

Answer (score 2):

Your terminal operates in line mode. So when you type the characters

```
hi
```

the program does not read them yet. They are just *echoed* to your terminal. When you press **Enter**, then all characters (`hi` plus a newline) are sent to the stdin of your program. These are read in character by character and then output. Thus, the text appears *twice* in your terminal.

If you want to change this, you have to put your terminal into *character mode* and switch *local echo off*. Libraries like **ncurses** can help you with that.

Comment: omg thanks now i get why its happening